# Converting object type to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue type

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am writing a program that uses the Microsoft Dynamics CRM API to populate a form with information gained from an EntityCollection given by the CRM. My issue is that the Entity is comprised of `KeyValuePair<string, object>` and this is causing a headache. some of the objects in the kvps are of type `OptionSetValue` during runtime and I need a way actually access the value because `OptionSetValue` require an additional accessor.

Here's some example code to demonstrate my problem ('e' is the Entity):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> thePair in e.Attributes.ToList())
{
    int theResult = thePair.Value;
}
```

In the above example the program will compile but will throw an expection during runtime because it will try to convert from `OptionSetValue` to `int32`.

Here's what I would like to accomplish somehow:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> thePair in e.Attributes.ToList())
{
    int theResult = thePair.Value.Value;
}
```

In this scenario the `.Value` accessor would return the value I need, but since the C# compiler does not know that `thePair` is of type `OptionSetValue` until runtime, it will not compile because the object type does not have a `.Value` member.

Any thoughts or need for clarification on my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems typing this all out have given me some clarity as I fixed this issue less than 5 minutes after this post. You can simply typecast use (OptionSetValue)

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> thePair in e.Attributes.ToList())
{
    int theResult = (OptionSetValue)thePair.Value.Value;
}
```